What is the significance of the Teivah landing on Mt. Ararat?
There's many mountains in Judaism that have extreme religious significance. Har Sinai, Har HaMoriah, Har Gerizim, Har Eval, Har Carmel, etc. I would expect the same to be true of not only the first mountain mentioned in the Torah, but the mountain where the new founders of humanity would start their mission of reshaping the world. However, I haven't found an explanation for why Hashem made the Teivah land on Mt. Ararat.
In terms of Rishonim, all I have found who even mentioned the mountain is Radak, who has suggested that Mt. Ararat could have been the tallest mountain, or that the Teivah happened to be in the general area. He seems dissatisfied with both explanations, and both seem to take the approach of "it was the most convenient area to land". However, my question still stands. Even if it was the most convenient, it still does not explain the significance of Mt. Ararat. This is a named mountain, if there was nothing to glean from the exact location/name, the Torah could have written "a mountain" or "a tall mountain".
The Talmud (Sanhedrin 96a) links Sancheriv to Mt. Ararat by having him find a plank of the Teivah there and forming it into an idol. Does this Aggadah play a role in explaining the significance of Mt. Ararat? If so, what is the meaning behind it?

Re "him find a plank of the Teivah there and forming it into an idol." - there are also Midrashic sources that say the gallows of Haman were from wood from the Teivah.

Perhaps not the best explanation, but a possible practical explanation is that Ararat is in the region of Turkey which connects Asia and Europe and would have made the split between the descendants of the sons of Noach simpler. Yefet goes to Europe, Shem and Cham split Asia and later some of Cham's descendants branch off to Africa.

@Harel13 very nice. Does this idea depend on the current mount ararat being the biblical one?

@RabbiKaii yes.
